# Removing an element works only sometimes

Tags: javascript

My click event works with jQuery but not with Vanilla JS.

This is how it works with jQuery:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.mt-remove-keyword', function() {
  alert('jQuery');
});
```

This is how I thought that it should work but it did not (maybe because my element is dynamic):

```js
const mtRemoveKeywords = document.querySelectorAll('.mt-remove-keyword');
for (let mtRemoveKeyword of mtRemoveKeywords) {
  mtRemoveKeyword.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        alert('JS');
  });
}
```

So I have used `document` as the selector to bubble it down to the main selector:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('mt-remove-keyword')) {
    console.log(e.target.classList);
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();    
  }
});
```

The goal is to remove the parent element of the target.
The problem is, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Feel free to test it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqgosmh1/). Just add a couple of texts to the yellow section and then try to delete them.

Comment: `e.target.closest('.selectorOfThatParentElement').remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I could resolve this issue (with help of epascarello):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('mt-remove-keyword') || e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('mt-remove-keyword')) {
    e.target.closest('.mt-keyword').remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The target might be different than what you think it is. In that case the parents might be off. So better to use closest to walk the tree.

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  var mtKeyword = e.target.closest('.mt-keyword');
  mtKeyword && mtKeyword.remove();
});
```

It would be better to bind the event listener to the parent element so not every document click is tracked.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution works only sometimes. Since only sometimes I get into that if statement. `console.log(e.target.classList);` returns sometimes _["svg-inline--fa", "fa-times-circle", "fa-w-16", "mt-remove-keyword", value: "svg-inline--fa fa-times-circle fa-w-16 mt-remove-keyword"]_ and sometimes _[""]_. I guess that must be because of the font awesome icon that I am using.

Comment: It is unclear how it would not work. If the element is being clicked on it will be detected by the parent and the closest will walk up the tree and find the element with the mt-keyword class. The event is going to be whatever element was clicked on exactly. You can use `event.currentTarget` instead which will be the element the event is attached to.